# How to get all records that contain a value or sub-array of that column?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I got a trouble with MariaDB. I have sql table with column where I decided to keep a JSON array. Does anyone know how to make a correct SELECT to get all records that contains a value or subarray of that column. For example:

```
rank = ["25","26","30"];
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(rank, '$') AS rarray
FROM table 
WHERE "25" IN rarray; Or WHERE ["25", "26"] IN rarray;
```

Thank you!

Comment: The title of a question is not for saying hello.  It's for providing a useful summary of your question which others can use when searching for a similar question because it shows up in search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this out:

```
select column_names from table 
where json_search(rank, "one", "25") is not NULL;
```

json_search finds path of "25" in column rank and returns null if it is not found. Above query filters out rows where json_search returns null, thus giving out all rows where "25" was found.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work that way. This one works SELECT * from table
where json_contains(rank, '["25"]'). And this one also SELECT * from table
where json_contains(rank, '["25","26"]') But if some array doesn't contain the both values it returns Null. I need if at least one value is in array. Of course I can do it by adding where json_contains(rank, '["25"]') OR json_contains(rank, '["26"]'). Would it be an expensive request if I have 5 of 6 values?

Comment: This should work as well as above. What error did you get? 

Also, this will work without square brackets-  SELECT * from sv_event_category where json_contains(rank, '"25"')

Comment: Json functions will be costly. How many rows do you have in that table?

Comment: I think there will be quite a lot rows. I have never used JSON's in SQL . Is there any ways of optimization?

Comment: It will need to compute json_contains or json_search for all rows to do this. I can't think of good way to index it. :(